# Creating Image Files from ImageBase64 then Zip the Image Files in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, base64, zip

so currently i'm tasked with converting a list of base64 to an image in flutter web. I've tried to use the archive package for flutter web, and i have written this code :

```
...
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';
...

var encoder = ZipEncoder();
var archive = Archive();

 for (String imgB64 in ListOfB64) {
   Uint8List imageByte = base64.decode(imgB64);
   ArchiveFile archiveFiles = 
   ArchiveFile.stream("filename.png",imageByte.lengthInBytes,imageByte as InputStreamBase);
   archive.addFile(archiveFiles);
 }

var outputStream = OutputStream(byteOrder: LITTLE_ENDIAN,);
var bytes = encoder.encode(archive,level: Deflate.BEST_COMPRESSION,output: outputStream);

download("test.zip",bytes) //download the recently created .zip file
```

but i always get the error of
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Expected a value of type 'InputStreamBase', but got one of type 'NativeUint8List'` but it seems that i can't find a way to convert the Uint8List to InputStreamBase.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I figured this out if you still need it. I was trying to do the same thing. Just wrap your bytes file in this 'InputStream()', i.e. InputStream(bytesHere).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).